# Confused by GLSL attribute types / versions

Tags: opengl, glsl, opentk

When should I use each of the following methods to recieve data in glsl ?

```
layout(points) in;
in vec3 pos;
uniform float x;
```

As far as I understood, "in" means that it's an attribute, rather than a uniform. Uniforms are available in all shaders, while in defines an attribute for this specific shader. Also uniforms are passed via glUniformTYPE while attributes (and I'm not sure about this) have to be passed via a buffer.

I'm trying to avoid opengl's built in functions like glMatrix etc. because tutorials suggested this is basically depricated / old style. Is that correct? If so, how would I assign indices to a buffer for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The three lines you pasted specify totally different things.

```
layout(points) in;
```

This looks like from an *input qualification* for the *Geometry Shader* stage. It declares that this geometry shader is getting `GL_POINTS` as the input primitive type (i.e. you must be drawing `GL_POINTS`). It's usually followed by a similar declaration for the kind of primitives which are then outputted from the Geometry Shader, for instance

```
layout(triangle_strip, max_vertices=3) out; // drawing triangles
```

---

```
in vec3 pos;
```

This instead declares a generic "input" for this shader stage, of type vec3. Depending on the actual shader stage its meaning can be different. For instance, in a Vertex Shader, it means that's a per-vertex attribute -- i.e. a bunch of data which is unique per-vertex¹. In a Geometry Shader you would get *entire primitives* as input. In a Fragment Shader a rasterized value.

In the Vertex Shader case, each vertex processed will get its own "pos" from a suitable configured input array, *usually*² from a Buffer Object which has been previously bound to the `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` binding point and has been configured to provide data to that attribute via a `glVertexAttribPointer` call.

*OR*, it could be an input to the Fragment Shader. In that case it's a per-fragment attribute, which (in the default case in which there are no extra qualifications) has undergone perspective-corrected interpolation. For instance, the Vertex Shader can output a color for each vertex:

```
#version 330
in vec3 position;
in vec3 input_color; // attribute as before

out vec3 color; // output towards the next shader stage

// (potentially) ran once per input vertex
void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);
    color = input_color;
}
```

and the fragment shader can pick the interpolated color:

```
#version 330

in vec3 color; // automatically "paired" to the VS output, i.e. the previous shader stage 
               // gets perspective-correct interpolation


out vec4 screenColor; // output => drawn on the screen

// (potentially) ran once per drawn fragment
void main() {
    screenColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
}
```

**So, the meaning of "in" and "out" depends on the particular shader stage they get used in.**

---

```
uniform float x;
```

This just means "x" is a uniform of type float for the entire shader program. It can't be changed from within the shader program; all shader stages will see it (they just need to declare it).

---

> If so, how would I assign indices to a buffer for example?

What do you mean with this?

---

> Is there a tutorial on modern opengl drawing which makes these things clear and sticks to modern standards, while also covering all the basics ?

Yes, for instance http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/ .

¹ There are exceptions to this rule, for instance the Attribute Divisor, but let's keep it simple.

² Read: what you should do. You can avoid using buffers and specifying vertex attribute values directly, but what's very likely to happen is that a buffer will be allocated behind the scenes by the GL driver.